# Why does std atomic insert 5 to the stack

Tags: c++, assembly, g++

I wanted to see how `std::atomic` is translated to assembly. To do that I wrote the following code but there is something I do not understand.

The following code:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::atomic<int> a;
    a.fetch_add(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Is compiled by GCC to:

```
1 |  push    rbp
2 |  mov     rbp, rsp
3 |  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
4 |  mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5
5 |  mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
6 |  lea     rax, [rbp-12]
7 |  lock xadd       DWORD PTR [rax], edx
8 |  mov     eax, 0
9 |  pop     rbp
10|  ret
```

Why does GCC push "5" (on line 4) onto the stack?

Comment: Try compiling with optimizations on.  Slightly modified live: https://godbolt.org/z/4pio0o (to ensure `a` is used)

Comment: This seems to be only added if `fetch_add()` is used on the object, even though godbolt marks it as result of declaration of `std::atomic`. No idea what it is though. https://godbolt.org/z/6p89Xd

Comment: I suspect, `5` is the value of [memory_order_seq_cst](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_base.h#L80) mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take the godbolt link Richard Critten very helpfully posted in a comment, and change the GCC command line to use `-O0`, the literal 5 reappears. Tellingly, it also shows up in

```
std::__atomic_base<int>::operator int() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        ...
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 5
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, eax
        call    std::operator&(std::memory_order, std::__memory_order_modifier)
```

so the literal `5` is eventually passed as an argument to that call, in `%edi`.

Since the argument is `std::memory_order`, we can look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) and see

```
typedef enum memory_order {
    memory_order_relaxed,
    memory_order_consume,
    memory_order_acquire,
    memory_order_release,
    memory_order_acq_rel,
    memory_order_seq_cst
} memory_order;
```

which, literally implemented, will give `memory_order_seq_cst = 5`.

Note that `memory_order_seq_cst` is the default for [`fetch_add`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add)'s ordering parameter, so you'd expect to see it passed as an argument.

Comment: `-O0` is the default, and obviously what the OP used when compiling.  (You can tell from making a frame pointer, using `mov eax,0` instead of `xor eax,eax`, and not optimizing to `lock add` instead of `xadd` when the result of `fetch_add` isn't used.)

Comment: If `fetch_add` is compiled to `lock xadd`, does this mean that `enum memory_order` is not used?